# When doing ghusl or wudu how do I ensure if a part is completely washed if that part was already wet?

Tags: practical-islam, wudu, ghusl

Whenever I do ghusl or wudu My feet and my hands and private parts get wet(as sunnah). Then when i start purifying(wudu or ghusl) myself I can find *itminan*(certainty) that I have washed the part completely.

1. My First Solution was to drying parts and and dipping parts that I can't was in a water container(like feet because floor is wet). But it takes significant amount of time (10-15 minutes).
2. My Second solution was to rub every such part with soap, the soap also gave an indicator how much i've washed.But its also time consuming.

**I just wanted to ask how do you deal with this problem? And how do i do this when I am in a public bathroom without soap and towel?**

Kindly Share What Allah Has Given You!

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like your whole limb most likely is washed then there no need for all that unless you're certain that a part haven't been washed